# Export and Import with special unicode characters

Tags: export, import, character-encoding

I exported a list of characters say:

```
ClearAll[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]];
Export["hello.txt", {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "List"];
```

the file has the correct symbols when opened with a text editor, however, when I imported it with *Mathematica*:

```
old = Import["hello.txt", "List"]
```

I get:

```
{t, r, Î¸, Ï}
```

Any idea of how can I recover the original symbols?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to specify the correct character encoding:

```
Export["hello.txt", {t, r, θ, ϕ}, "List"];

old = Import["hello.txt", "List", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]

(* ==> {"t", "r", "θ", "ϕ"} *)
```

Comment: oh perfect it worked!, many thankx!